# Limit of $\frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{f(3x)-f(x)}$ when $x\to0$, for $f$ twice continuously differentiable in a neighborhood of $0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, derivatives

> Let $f$ be a two times continuously differentiable function in a neighborhood of $x=0$. Find
>   $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{f(3x)-f(x)}$$
>   when,
>
> a. $f'(0)\neq 0 $
>
> b. $f'(0)= 0 $ but $f''(0)\neq 0 $

Thoughts, I feel like this should be a straightforward question but I'm not sure how for example, how to use the conditions to find the limit.  Like for example for a, how does the derivative at $0$ not equalling $0$ help me get the limit.

I was thinking of using L'Hopital's Rule as I get $0/0$ when I plug in.
If I use it, I take derivative of top and bottom and get 
$$\frac{2f'(2x)-f'(x)}{3f'(3x)-f'(x)}.$$ Plugging in 0 I get, $(2f'(0)-f'(0))/(3f'(0)-f'(0))$.  For part a, I know $f'(0)$ does not equal 0. So I get $f'(0)/2f'(0)$  I know $f'(0)$ is just some number not equal to 0 so I get limit equal to $1/2$.

For part b, I will have to do L'Hopital's Rule twice so I get taking first derivative:
$$\frac{2f'(2x)-f'(x)}{3f'(3x)-f'(x)}$$. Plug in, I still get $0/0$.  I take a second derivative and get :
$$\frac{4f''(2x)-f''(x)}{9f''(3x) -f''(x)}.$$  Plug in 0, I get $(4f''(0)- f''(0))/(9f''(0)-f''(0))$ So limit is $3/8$.

I have no idea if this is correct, however.

Comment: Did you check the conditions for L'H rule to apply?

Comment: I get 0/0 so I figured it applies.  Is there some other conditions, I'm not aware of?

Comment: Huh? You do have a statement of L'H at hand, including conditions, right?

Comment: I searched through my notes.  I can't find any.  Could you explain the conditions to me?  Thanks.

Comment: You could not find any condition to L'H in your notes? But you did find a **statement** of L'H, right? What did it say? In general, theorems start with "Let A, B, C, ..., denote objects such that properties P, Q, ..., hold" and end with "Then results R, S, ..., hold" Here we are after P, Q, ...

Comment: This is what in says in my notes:Suppose f,g-differentiable in (a,b).  Suppose lim f(x)=0, x approaching a from the right, is equal to lim g(x)=0, x approaching a from the right.  then the limit f'(x)/g(x) as x goes to a exists.

Comment: This is verbatim: what I wrote (the def given in this article) :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: So... what is your question?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your results are correct. This is an alternative approach which uses Taylor expansions.

Under the first hypothesis, $f(t)=f(0)+f'(0)t+o(t)$, as $t\to 0$. Hence
\begin{align}\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{f(3x)-f(x)}&=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(f(0)+f'(0)(2x)+o(x))-(f(0)+f'(0)x+o(x))}{(f(0)+f'(0)(3x)+o(x))-(f(0)+f'(0)x+o(x))}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(0)(2x-x)+o(x)}{f'(0)(3x-x)+o(x)}=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}

For b) $f(t)=f(0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)t^2+o(t^2)$, as $t\to 0$. Therefore 
\begin{align}
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(2x)-f(x)}{f(3x)-f(x)}&=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(f(0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)(2x)^2+o(x^2))-(f(0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2+o(x^2))}{(f(0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)(3x)^2+o(x^2))-(f(0)+\frac{1}{2}f''(0)x^2+o(x^2))}\\
&=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f''(0)(4x^2-x^2)+o(x^2)}{f''(0)(9x^2-x^2)+o(x^2)}=\frac{3}{8}.
\end{align}